# Place StripeLine On Top of Series (Adjust Z-Index/Z-Order)

Tags: asp.net, charts, asp.net-4.0, data-visualization, mschart

I'm building a Column chart with `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` and would like to show a dotted line to represent an average. [StripeLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.stripline.aspx) seems to be exactly what I'm looking for except it sits under/behind the columns (see example).

Is there a way to adjust the "Z-Index" of a `StripeLine` so that it is shown in front of/on top of the `Series`?

I don't see a property for this and changing the order I add the `Series` and `StripeLine` doesn't make a difference.

[image: Sample Chart]

Comment: It doesn't look like you can... All I see is the Z-order for StripLines, and it's determined programmatically:

"The Z-order of StripLine objects is determined by their order of occurrence in the StripLinesCollection object. This means that the first occurrence is drawn first; the second occurrence is drawn second, and so on."

I think they have their own separate order that is always behind the chart area

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Annotations

```
double avg = Chart1.Series[0].Points.Average(p => p.XValue);
double lineHeight = avg;
HorizontalLineAnnotation ann = new HorizontalLineAnnotation();
ann.AxisX = Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
ann.AxisY = Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
ann.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
ann.AnchorY = lineHeight;
ann.IsInfinitive = true;
ann.ClipToChartArea = Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name; ann.LineColor = Color.Red; ann.LineWidth = 3;
Chart1.Annotations.Add(ann);
```

HTML Code

```
<asp:Chart runat="server" ID="Chart1"   ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation"  Width="800px" Height="400px" OnClick="Chart1_Click">
    <ChartAreas  >
    <asp:ChartArea></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
    <series>  
           <asp:Series Name="Students" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105">  
            <Points>
                <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="jon" XValue="5" YValues="4" />
                <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="kon" XValue="15" YValues="44" />
                <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="pol" XValue="85" YValues="90" />
            </Points>
           </asp:Series>                        
      </series> 
</asp:Chart>
```

Code for Text Annotation

```
TextAnnotation txtAnn = new TextAnnotation();
txtAnn.AxisX = Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
txtAnn.AxisY = Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
txtAnn.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
txtAnn.AnchorY = lineHeight;
txtAnn.AnchorX = Chart1.Series[0].Points.Last().XValue;
txtAnn.AnchorAlignment = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
txtAnn.Text = "DivisionOne(35.5)";
txtAnn.ClipToChartArea = Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name; txtAnn.ForeColor =  Color.Red; 
Chart1.Annotations.Add(txtAnn);
```

You can get more information here

[More Information About Annotations](http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/WebChart2005/Annotations.html)

[Chart Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/chartpic000003.png/)

Comment: doesn't look like I can add a title/text caption... though you did answer my question, thanks

Comment: You can use text annotation for that.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I'll upvote if you could please add that to your answer.

Comment: Added. Also i have added a link where you can find how to place annotations on the chart.

Comment: Would be nice to be able to include in the legend rather than adding a text annotation - any idea if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the text property of the stripeline

> Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.StripLines(0).Text = "Line
>   Title"