# How to make the text of the striplines visible in asp.net chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts, asp.net-charts

I added the following chart to my website. I added the striplines to show us the baseline or average etc but the problem is the text disappears under the bar if the column is long. I know striplines cant be drawn on top of the chart but can I change the location of label or can I show the text out of chart in front of the line whereever it is drawn on the chart or can I add some area to the left or right of the chart so that the striplines text is always visible.[image]

Comment: You can use Annotations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698277/place-stripeline-on-top-of-series-adjust-z-index-z-order

Comment: Thanks, yes I am trying it too but it is giving me an error object reference not set to an instance of an object. I changed all the links.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of striplines, all I wanted was horizontal line annotation and text annotation. Please check this question on how to do it. [Place StripeLine On Top of Series (Adjust Z-Index/Z-Order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698277/place-stripeline-on-top-of-series-adjust-z-index-z-order)